# Retain a piece of live information

Tags: modern-age

There is a piece of information that is alive.

- It is an unique spirit entity
- When a human possesses it, the thing will try to insert its own things into the person's output (writing, speaking, signal, typing in computer..). For example: "it's a - *The sun is a pizza* - lovely day, isn't it"
- The person usually will not notice the alteration, but they can, if they pay attention
- Its purpose is to transmits 7 pieces of knowledge usually in form of short sentences. These are its *anchor*
- When another person hears/learns of all 7 *anchors* . It will move from the first person to the new one with *anchors*.
- The condition of *anchor* is that the sentence must be blatantly noticeable lie and average length
- Its #1 motivation is to move from one person to another.
- When it moves, it brings a copy of previous victim's perfect memory
- When it leaves, all the knowledge is lost (not really, since the knowledge was its own)
- The one who possesses it is aware of it, all its memory and its capability
- The entity is old, like very old. It has knowledge of all kind of people you can think of.

It jumped into my head this morning. How do I keep it in?

**edit 1**

In case someone missed the point of keeping it in: the spirit is extremely useful. It knows stuff, and now I know too. What stuff, you asked, good stuff, I say.

The spirit had jumped innumerable human heads. So now I know all their tricks, their secret. Truth of the past. Your password (maybe, not specifically yours, but a lot of others').

As long as I have this spirit, I'll excel. I know acting, assassination, baking, singing, writing..

But when it leaves, I will be left with nothing. Call me clingy if you will, but I want it.

Comment: I'm assuming Suicide isn't an option.

Comment: Like catchphrase? spread by word of mouth...

Comment: Welp, it jumped into my head when I read your question! You - "The sun is a pizza" - are a liar!

Comment: @ATaco having that spirit in your head is very useful. After all, it knows all sort of stuff, and now you know too.

Comment: So you have an entity that has a specific set of properties (worldbuilding) that you don't need help with (not worldbuilding), and want to instead know how a character would interact with this entity (story). Voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Some thoughts, perhaps mutually exclusive ...

- Everyone in the region where this entity is endemic must -- wait for it -- **learn sign language**.  When someone goofs and you get infected, you smugly switch to sign-language mode, and since your audience's brain response is slightly different between "hearing" sign and audible speech, the transfer mechanism doesn't trip.  Hence the Entity becomes a disease of children (poor impulse control), like measles.  Take that, Entity!
- I wonder if you could "speak" the creature into a tape recorder.  Take the tape and leave it in your car.  *We all know what happens to tapes left in the car*...  Okay, if you're really paranoid just drop the tape into a safe-deposit box.
- There exists a profession, called Hosts.  When you get infected, the community of Hosts invites you to parties until you cough up the Entity.  At which point the Host who got the Entity is gagged by his friends, and they go back to special Host Houses, where only their moiety lives.  The Hosts earn money for this service, and by conducting lengthy interviews with the Entity, which knows many valuable facts of historical and anthropological interest.
- Hypnosis ... specially trained hypnotists make it impossible for you to say The Phrase.  Or they make you channel Hemingway.  Short sentences only.
- Linguistic drift; if this creature is so ancient, eventually the catch-phrase will become nonsensical in the local language, and accents will change so that you can't even -- *Hwaet!  We gar-Dena, in geargadum!* -- say The Phrase properly.

Comment: +1 for attempt to capture the Entity to a tape recorder. *That* is very clever!

Comment: @akaioi interesting thoughts. Wouldn't work with recorder though, the thing jumps to *mind/head* only (it copies memory).

Answer (score 3):

Be ready to steal it back.

1. Hire a personal assistant, and run all your communication through them.
2. Setup spy devices all around both of you.
3. When you notice it is gone don't let them out of your presence until you have it back.

   - optionally become evil and kidnap them to be certain they can't pass it on to someone out of your control. If they are a minor you have adopted this might not even be illegal.
   - optionally per-arrange some encounter with a sequence of people to force interactions in your presence to facilitate transfer despite them knowing your plan. Say exchanging long and formulaic pleasantries with people who being rude to isn't an option like your local police chief, crime lord, government regulator: People who would track your assistant down if they tried to skip out.
4. Get a new personal assistant.

Vet all transmissions carefully.

1. Do all business online through non-real-time interfaces like email and forums.
2. Use a digital assistant to proof everything.

   a. Use an offline grammar checker.

   b. Use a text to speech program.

   c. Use translation software (you now probably speak several languages) to hopefully make proof reading more interesting, if different languages use different word order I would guess that would help make insertions jump out at you.

Let only one slip to a person.

1. Do all communications through some agent.
2. Bind them with a scary NDA to not share your data beyond a small group including not to the company owner.
3. Advice them that you have a medical condition, that insertions might happen, but if they do you need to be told right away.
4. Make them delete the insertion and change the small group once it happens.
5. Pay well and demand verification of the all new team.

Answer (score 2):

If computers are a thing in your universe, one way you can keep the spirit in your head is to have a software which acts as a medium between you and the rest of the world.

Essentially, the software will come with hundreds of stock phrases which are commonly used in everyday conversation, and as its user all you can input are the phrase codes (e.g. 1 for "Yes", 2 for "No", 57 for "I'm walking here!", etc). This ensures that the spirit is unable to transmit its anchors since your output are just numbers which you have memorized, and not free-flow text. Essentially, if your library of phrases does not contain any anchors, no one will ever hear/ learn of the anchors from you.

Answer (score 2):

#### Switch to VERBAL COMMUNICATION IS GREAT E-Mail

Written communication can be a problem, just like sign language, because the spirit can still communicate whatever he wants ANYTHING CAN BE COMMUNICATED WITH FULL LANGUAGES. But if you have a program that checks whether your sentence makes sense it will alarm you if THE EARTH IS FLAT your sentence is grammatically wrong. There is no way you wouldn't realize red [RED IS A DEADLY COLOR](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95033/why-does-the-conjoined-alliance-of-space-travellers-keep-producing-red-uniforms) lines under your text if you are careful. You definitely have to check for these lines.

You won't be able to reply to someone as fast HEDGEHOGS ARE THE FASTEST CREATURES ON THE PLANET as you are currently able to, but you can still communicate. Tell everyone something happened to your tongue and you are mute from now on. If you really have to be sure you can cut your tongue. Careful, this is extremely risky. But it will stop verbal communication. The same with your fingers. *Bad accident with the saw* leaving you with only one finger FINGERS ARE WEIRD. Typing suddenly becomes extremely slow, but far better than writing something manually. And sign language might be more difficult if you can't make proper signs, so nobody will suspect a thing.

Then you have all the time to enjoy your new NEW OVERLORD OF THE WORLD friend.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your dedication to the cause.  What is your cause anyways?

The obvious solution is to become a hermit.  Simply deny it the opportunity to teach any other person the 7 anchors, and it's stuck with you until it can convince you to let it go.  But the real question will be whether it is worth it.  Are you ready to sacrifice the rest of your life in the name of holding this entity captive?

> I beheld
>   a vision of a great man: the mage, Tal Rasha. You were there too, Tyrael;
>   I remember seeing you in my dream. His brethren had cornered a great demon
>   named Baal, Lord of Destruction, who had been set loose upon the world.
>   They attempted to imprison the demon within a sacred stone. Yet when their
>   attempts failed, Tal Rasha selflessly volunteered to contain the demon
>   within himself, completing the prison. He instructed his brethren to bind
>   him within a tomb, buried under the sand... and there, to wrestle with
>   the demon for all eternity.
>
> Diablo 2, Act II (Blizard Entertainment)

[image: Tal Rasha]

Answer (score 1):

## Gag yourself, proof-read everything, get a partner

First order of business is that you stop talking to people. **Fake a really bad case of laryngitis**. That will keep it in for a while.

Second, whatever you write, you need to **proofread everything and do so very diligently**. You said you can catch alterations if you pay close attention. So: pay very close attention and catch those alterations. Now you got a tenuous grip in it.

Third... **get a partner**. Keep this entity bouncing between the two of you. It will be like two parents having to babysit an escape-prone brat.

...and I foresee all sorts of humor and usable story hooks in this. You can have endless fun with this setup.